# Using uniform cost search on a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, distance

Good day, I have an 11x11 matrix (shown below) where the 0s represent open spaces and the 1s represent walls. The horizontal and vertical movements are weighted at 1 and the diagonal movements are weighted at sqrt(2) The matrix looks as follows:

```
 `board = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],
           [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
           [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
           [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
           [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
           [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
           [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
           [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
           [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
           [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]`
```

My goal is to write a Uniform cost search code in python to find the most cost effective path from a starting point (e.g [1,1]) to an end point (e.g [5,1]). Most of the code I have come across works with graphs and not matrices. I need help with working around this with a matrix.

I am fairly new at python and all help and advice will be highly appreciated. I am using python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody seems to know an easy answer to this question I will post my (hopefully correct) answer. The used approach is not really efficient and based on a flood fill like algorithm.

First we define a list with all possible directions. Those are represented by a lambda function which return the new indices (`x`and `y`), the current weight and the current path:

```
from math import sqrt

dirs = [
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x, y - 1, z + 1, p + [(x, y)]),  # up
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x, y + 1, z + 1, p + [(x, y)]),  # down
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x - 1, y, z + 1, p + [(x, y)]),  # left
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x + 1, y, z + 1, p + [(x, y)]),  # right
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x - 1, y - 1, z + sqrt(2), p + [(x, y)]),  # up left
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x + 1, y - 1, z + sqrt(2), p + [(x, y)]),  # up right
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x - 1, y + 1, z + sqrt(2), p + [(x, y)]),  # down left
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x + 1, y + 1, z + sqrt(2), p + [(x, y)])  # down right
]
```

Then we create some functions. The first one checks if the indices calculated by the directions are valid indices for the matrix and that there is no wall.

```
def valid(grid, x, y):
    return 0 <= x < len(grid) and 0 <= y < len(grid[0]) and grid[x][y] == 0
```

The `adjacent` function yields every direction for every cell at the `frontier` (imagine it like a wave) and the `flood` function moves the wave one step forwards and replaces the old step with walls (`1`).

```
def adjacent(grid, frontier):
    for (x, y, z, p) in frontier:
        for d in dirs:
            nx, ny, nz, np = d(x, y, z, p)
            if valid(grid, nx, ny):
                yield (nx, ny, nz, np)

def flood(grid, lst):
    res = list(adjacent(grid, frontier))
    for (x, y, z, p) in frontier:
        grid[x][y] = 1
    return res
```

In the following funtion we call the defined functions and return a tuple of the weight of the shortest path and the shortest path.

```
def shortest(grid, start, end):
    start, end = tuple(start), tuple(end)
    frontier = [(start[0], start[1], 0, [])]
    res = []
    while frontier and grid[end[0]][end[1]] == 0:
        frontier = flood(grid, frontier)
        for (x, y, z, p) in frontier:
            if (x, y) == end:
                res.append((z, p + [(x, y)]))
    if not res:
        return ()
    return sorted(res)[0]
```

I tested it for `(0, 0)` to `(8, 8)` and the output seems plausable. It will probably fail if the cost for two horizontal / vertical steps is lower than the cost for the equal diagonal step.

EDIT: Result for `(0, 0)` to `(8, 8)` with `P` as path:

```
[[P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,P],
 [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,P],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,P],
 [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,P],
 [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,P],
 [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,P],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,P],
 [0,0,0,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,1,P],
 [0,0,P,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,P],
 [0,P,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,P],
 [0,0,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,0]]
```

Weight: `39.071067811865476`

EDIT 2: Add copy paste version.

```
from math import sqrt

board = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],
         [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
         [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
         [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
         [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
         [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
         [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
         [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

dirs = [
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x, y - 1, z + 1, p + [(x, y)]),  # up
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x, y + 1, z + 1, p + [(x, y)]),  # down
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x - 1, y, z + 1, p + [(x, y)]),  # left
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x + 1, y, z + 1, p + [(x, y)]),  # right
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x - 1, y - 1, z + sqrt(2), p + [(x, y)]),  # up left
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x + 1, y - 1, z + sqrt(2), p + [(x, y)]),  # up right
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x - 1, y + 1, z + sqrt(2), p + [(x, y)]),  # down left
    lambda x, y, z, p: (x + 1, y + 1, z + sqrt(2), p + [(x, y)])  # down right
]

def valid(grid, x, y):
    return 0 <= x < len(grid) and 0 <= y < len(grid[0]) and grid[x][y] == 0

def adjacent(grid, frontier):
    for (x, y, z, p) in frontier:
        for d in dirs:
            nx, ny, nz, np = d(x, y, z, p)
            if valid(grid, nx, ny):
                yield (nx, ny, nz, np)

def flood(grid, frontier):
    res = list(adjacent(grid, frontier))
    for (x, y, z, p) in frontier:
        grid[x][y] = 1
    return res

def shortest(grid, start, end):
    start, end = tuple(start), tuple(end)
    frontier = [(start[0], start[1], 0, [])]
    res = []
    while frontier and grid[end[0]][end[1]] == 0:
        frontier = flood(grid, frontier)
        for (x, y, z, p) in frontier:
            if (x, y) == end:
                res.append((z, p + [(x, y)]))
    if not res:
        return ()
    return sorted(res)[0]

print(shortest(board, (0, 0), (8, 8)))
```

Comment: every time i try to run it, i get an error which says Type Error: ' module' object is not iterable.This is how i am running the code: print(shortest(board, [0,0], [8,8]))

Comment: I added a copy paste version of my sample code (which definitely works on my maschine). I also added a tuple cast so you can pass lists as start and end. On a side note: this function will change your board, so if you need it in other places consider copying it before calling the function.